# Kohana ORM - Duplicate instance / db entry

Tags: kohana, kohana-3, kohana-orm, kohana-db

I'd like to "duplicate" an ORM object and then save it into the database (with a new primary key), but I am not able to unset the primary key of the copied object.

```
    $orm1 = new Model1($id);
    if($orm1->loaded()) {
     $orm2 = $orm1;
     $orm2->id = null; //something like this?
     unset($orm2->_primary_key); //or like this?
     $orm2->save(); //I would like to create a new entry in the db but it doesn't work
    }
```

I hope I am clear enough... Basically, how can I "save again" a model in the db...?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to copy ORM data from one model to another:

```
// save current data
$data = $orm1->as_array();
$orm2 = new Model1();
$orm2->values($data);
$orm2->save();
```

This example uses separate ORM objects. You can load values back to `$orm1`, but don't forget to call `$orm1->clear()` before `$orm1->values($data)`. This resets the model to its unloaded state.

Note that `as_array` will also return `belongs_to` relationships.

Comment: Thanks! although I'm using it I didn't think about the as_array() function in this case. And I didn't know about the clear... :)

Comment: But actually, since $data will have the primary key value, shouldn't I unset it from the array before re-firing values() ??

Comment: Kohana will drop it automatically: http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/api/ORM#values

Comment: @biakaveron: +1 from my end, your answer helped me to write own logic in Kohana 2 [ Ya, we're still using K2 ] as values() method not value in K2.

Answer (score -1):

You might want to try this:

```
// Reset primary key
$this->_primary_key_value = NULL;
```

And do not forget about Object cloning: [Object Cloning](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php)

Comment: As you can see in the code in my question, I do clone the object, and i do try to unset the primary key value, but this does not work...

Comment: You did unset($orm2->_primary_key); but my suggestion is: $this->_primary_key_value = NULL; It's different. And what you did is not 'object cloning'. You just referenced the object.

Comment: `_primary_key_value` is a protected property, so you cant change it from the outside.

Comment: Yes, sorry about that. Can you try this: $orm2->clear(); $orm2->values($orm1->as_array()); $orm2->save(); Note that you may need to unset the primary key from ($orm1->as_array());